# Pulse News Style layout can be created using UICollectionview in iOS6?

Tags: layout, ios6, uicollectionview

Has anyone created a layout like Pulse News using UICollectionView? Please explain how or share the code, if possible.

If you haven't seen Pulse, here is the layout I'm looking for:

[image: pulse news ios screenshot]

Comment: I have combined a UITableView and a UICollectionView to implement exactly this. However, I am unable to get cell selection working in the UICollectionView (which is a subview of a table view cell). I think this is a big barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Though its 2 years since you asked this question, for the benefit of other users here,I am just answering. I just made a BBC news app clone UI just to learn. It follows the Pulse style UI. I have used UITableView and each row is a UICollectionView. I am sure, the other way round could be done too. Here is a link to the complete UI. It has no backend, otherwise it is a complete App ready to go with dummy data. https://github.com/anilputtabuddhi/NewsAppUI